# Como ler e processar com sucesso dados recebidos pela porta serial em Visual .NET?

Tags: .net, arduino

Tenho aqui um `arduino` que está a **detetar batidas num sinal line** level de audio.

Sempre que é **detetada** uma batida o `arduino` envia o caracter `b` para a porta serial.

Até aí eu já consegui fazer.

Agora eu estava a tentar fazer uma pequena interface gráfica que mostra as batidas por minuto em `visual .NET`.

Ou seja, eu tenho uma **SerialPort1** e sempre que ela receber um `b`, deve ser inicializado um `timer` ( *com um intervalo de 1 milisegundo defenido nas propriedades do timer ) até ao próximo `b` recebido.

O valor do **tempo** que passou entre a chegada dos **dois** `b` deve ser armazenado numa variável.

Depois fazer o mesmo para o **segundo** `b` recebido e o **terceiro**.

Enfim fazer isto até ter **4 valores** de tempo em 4 variáveis.

Depois de ter 4 variáveis é preciso dividir **60000 milisegundos** pela **média** entre as **4 variáveis** e mostrar o resultado ( *bpm - batidas por minuto* ) numa `TextBox`.

Depois repetir tudo ( *começar novamente a receber os `b`, armazenar as variáveis de tempo e mostrar o cálculo das **bpm** na `TextBox`, fazendo assim um refresh do valor* ).

Já que sou pouco experiente a programar, gostava de saber como conseguir pôr isto tudo a funcionar no `visual .NET` já que não estou a conseguir.

Consigo fazer o "connect" ao arduino mas parece estar algo errado no código que está dentro do ciclo "while(true)". Não aparece o cálculo das bpm's na textbox, em vez disso aparece "+/- infinito" ou então não aparece nada. O que está errado ?

Eu sei que depois vai ser preciso implementar código para fazer break ao ciclo infinito mas para já só queria mesmo era pôr a mostrar o cálculo das bpm's na textbox.

Muito Obrigado.

Tentei este código:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim time4beats As Integer
    Dim connected As Boolean
    Dim beatcount As Integer
    Dim beat1 As Integer
    Dim beat2 As Integer
    Dim beat3 As Integer
    Dim beat4 As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        SerialPort1.PortName = TextBox1.Text
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = TextBox2.Text
        SerialPort1.Open()
        connected = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        time4beats = time4beats + 1

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        beatcount = 0
        beat1 = 0
        beat2 = 0
        beat3 = 0
        beat4 = 0

        time4beats = 0

        While (True)

            If (SerialPort1.ReadChar().Equals("b") & beatcount.Equals(0)) Then

                Timer1.Start()
                beatcount = beatcount + 1

            ElseIf (SerialPort1.ReadChar().Equals("b") & beatcount.Equals(1)) Then

                Timer1.Stop()
                beat1 = time4beats

                time4beats = 0
                Timer1.Start()
                beatcount = beatcount + 1

            ElseIf (SerialPort1.ReadChar().Equals("b") & beatcount.Equals(2)) Then

                beat2 = time4beats
                Timer1.Stop()
                time4beats = 0
                Timer1.Start()
                beatcount = beatcount + 1

            ElseIf (SerialPort1.ReadChar().Equals("b") & beatcount.Equals(3)) Then

                beat3 = time4beats
                Timer1.Stop()
                time4beats = 0
                Timer1.Start()
                beatcount = beatcount + 1

            ElseIf (SerialPort1.ReadChar().Equals("b") & beatcount.Equals(4)) Then

                beat4 = time4beats
                Timer1.Stop()
                time4beats = 0

                beatcount = 0

                TextBox3.Text = (60000 / ((beat1 + beat2 + beat3 + beat4) / 4)).ToString

            End If
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```